# How to pass the correct params in PUT method in REST server (NodeJS, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I'm implement a simple high score board with RESTful, the server uses NodeJS and MySQL. I get the problem when implement the PUT method while the others (GET, POST, DELETE...) work well in both client and POSTMAN as I expected.

In MySQL, I create a table with only 2 values are "username" and "score".

Here is my route code:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  let userCtrl = require('./controllers/UserControllers');

  // routes
  app.route('/users')
    .get(userCtrl.get)
    .post(userCtrl.store);

  app.route('/users/:username')
    .get(userCtrl.detail)
    .put(userCtrl.update)
    .delete(userCtrl.delete);

  app.route('/leaderboard')
    .get(userCtrl.top);
};
```

Here is my controller source code:

```
'use strict';

const util = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = require('./../db.js');

module.exports = {
  get: (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM leaderboard';
    db.query(sql, (err, response) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(response);
    });
  },
  store: (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO leaderboard SET ? ';
    // sql = 'INSERT INTO leaderboard_log SET '
    let data = req.body;
    db.query(sql, [data], (err, response) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json({message: 'Insert success!'});
    });
  },
  // the 'update' here works well in POSTMAN
  update: (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'UPDATE leaderboard SET ? WHERE username = ?';
    let data = req.body;
    let username = req.params.username;
    db.query(sql, [data, username], (err, response) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json({message: 'Update success!'});
    });
  }
};
```

The client in javascript uses PUT method

```
function httpPut(theUrl, data, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: theUrl,
    success: callbackSuccess,
    error: callbackError,
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true
  });
}

// how to pass the params 'username, 'newScore' to httpPUT ?!?
function updateUser(username, newScore) {
  let data = {};
  data['username'] = username;
  data['score'] = newScore;
  httpPut(URL_PUT_USER + username, data, function(data) {
    // success
    console.log("success update");
  }, function(data) {
    // fail
    console.log("update error");
  });
}
```

The problem is the function

> updateUser(username, newScore)

which I don' know how to pass the param so that the **update: (req, res)** will understand.

Note that I tested using POSTMAN to update the record and the **update: (req, res)** works well.

Any help is appreciate. Thank you!.

PS: here is the error on server:

```
simple_leaderboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` maps to `store` operation, where your sql is defined as :

```
let sql = 'INSERT INTO leaderboard SET ? ';
```

This is not a valid SQL insert statement.

You probably want :

```
let sql = 'INSERT INTO leaderboard(username, data) VALUES(?, ?)';
let username = req.params.username;
let data = req.body;
db.query(sql, [username, data], ...
```

Comment: I follow the tutorial here: https://www.codementor.io/julieisip/learn-rest-api-using-express-js-and-mysql-db-ldflyx8g2 . That means **PUT** map to **update** operation.